# Is it possible to use SqlCmd to run scripts against a localdb database?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, localdb

I've got a large SQL script (1gb) that I'm trying to run against a `(localdb)\v11.0` instance, using `SqlCmd` in a command line window, but so far no commands I've tried have worked with it at all.

E.g.

```
sqlcmd.exe -S "(localdb)\v11.0" -Q "select 1"
```

fails with a generic connection error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

However

```
sqlcmd.exe -S "MY-PC" -Q "select 1"
```

is fine with the SQL Server instance on my PC.

"Allow Remote Connections" is set to true on the `(localdb)` instance and the user I'm running the `sqlcmd` with is the owner of it.

Does `Sqlcmd` actually work with `(localdb)` instances? Are there any other obvious things I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Hi,I have experienced this when using the wrong version of sqlcmd for the Localdb in question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214688/why-cant-i-connect-to-a-sql-server-2012-localdb-shared-instance
Is that possible?
O

Comment: Gah, yes that seems to be it. I navigated through to the latest Sql Server installation "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn", but looking more carefully, there's no SqlCmd.exe in there, so it would have defaulted back to the one set in my Env, rather than SQL\110 . When I run  sqlcmd from 110\tools\binn it's fine. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this can happen when you use the wrong version of SQLCMD for the LocalDB instance as described in this post...

[Why can't I connect to a SQL Server 2012 LocalDB shared instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214688/why-cant-i-connect-to-a-sql-server-2012-localdb-shared-instance)

Hth,
Ojf

Answer (score 0):

Change your working folder to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn

> cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn"

and try again...

> sqlcmd.exe -S "MY-PC"